# memberInfo.GetValue() C#

Tags: c#, reflection

How to get an instance's member's values?

With propertyInfos there is a `propertyInfo.GetValue(instance, index)`, but no such thing exists in memberInfo.

I searched the net, but it seems to stop at getting the member's name and type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think what you need is `FieldInfo`.

Answer (score 25):

You have to downcast to `FieldInfo` or `PropertyInfo`:

```
switch (memberInfo)
{
  case FieldInfo fieldInfo:
    return fieldInfo.GetValue(obj);
  case PropertyInfo propertyInfo:
    return propertyInfo.GetValue(obj);
  default:
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```